# Position issue with table when last cell changes size

Tags: html, css

```
<table>                                        
    <tbody>                                        
        <tr style="height:30px">                              
            <td>Has a Menu and is goes to the extreme left</td>
            <td style="position: absolute; right: 238px;">this cell has a Checkout image and needs to be close to the next cell</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; position: absolute; right: 12px;">has another menu and needs to go to the extreme right</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The second TD `style="position: absolute; right: 238px;"` needs to be able to resize itself based upon the last TD with `style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; position: absolute; right: 12px;"`.
The last TD/Cell is fine and needs to be exactly where it is and thats the reason I had to set the position: absolute.... But the TD before that needs to before it.
If I remove the the position:absolute on second TD then it goes to the left which I do not want. If I keep it as it is then when the the last TD decreases or increases in size if effects the screen position of the second TD - I need the second TD to always be close to the last TD
Can you help by redefining/refactoring the style for the td  with `style="position: absolute; right: 238px;"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `table` since you're not showing tabular data. Besides, giving `position:absolute` to a `td` sounds really strange, not sure it's even valid (so it might look ok in one browser, but maybe not in another, specially not in IE 7 and below, you might want to check that)

Instead, use `<div>`s and position them, should be easier.  Something like ...

```
<div style='overflow:auto'>
  <div style='float:left'>Has a Menu and is goes to the extreme left</div>
  <div style='float:right'>has another menu and needs to go to the extreme right</div>
  <div style='float:right'>this cell has a Checkout image and needs to be close to the next cell</div>
</div>
```

just as an example, you'd need to play with the positioning of course. Notice how the third of your 'cells' goes before the second.  That's not a typo, it's because they're floated to the right, so the right-most element goes first, and the next right-floated element stops next to it, etc.